# How to simplify $\frac{(x - 1)(7x + 6)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)^2 }-\frac{ 7}{ (x + 1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Iam having trouble simplifying this expression:$$\frac{(x - 1)(7x + 6)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)^2  }-\frac{ 7}{  (x + 1)}$$

What are the steps to simplify this?

I know you expand $(x + 1)^2$ to $(x + 1)(x + 1)$, and that you need to find a common denominator before adding the numerators together.

The final answer is $\quad\displaystyle\frac{-1}{x^2 + 2x + 1}.$

Thanks.

Comment: I think someone got the problem wrong: looks like it should be a $-$, not a $+$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to simplify the following:

$$\frac{(x-1)(7x + 6)}{(x-1)(x+1)^2} - \frac {7}{(x+1)}$$

First, we cancel the common factor $(x-1)$ in the left-hand fraction:

$$\frac{(x-1)(7x + 6)}{(x-1)(x+1)^2} - \frac {7}{(x+1)} = \frac{(7x + 6)}{(x+1)^2} - \frac {7}{(x+1)}$$

Now we find a common denominator to add the fractions, and see that we want both denominators to be $(x+1)^2$. To accomplish this, we can multiply the numerator and the denominator of the second fraction by the factor of $(x+1)$:

$$\frac{(7x + 6)}{(x+1)^2} - \frac{7}{(x+1)} \cdot \frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)} = \frac{(7x + 6)}{(x+1)^2} - \frac {7(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$ $$ = \frac{(7x + 6 - 7(x+1))}{(x+1)^2} \;=\;\frac{ -1}{(x+1)^2} $$ $$\;=\;\frac{-1}{x^2 + 2x + 1}$$

Comment: How did you get (x+1)^2 on the right hand side?

Comment: Because both denominators: $(x+1)$ and $(x+1)^2$ - divide $(x+1)^2$. Notice that $\dfrac{7(x+1)}{(x+1)^2} = \dfrac{7}{(x+1)}$

Comment: Ohh okay. Sort of starting to understand.

Comment: Why not by (x+1)^2?

Comment: Yeah I see you times by (x+1) to the right hand fraction, but shouldn't it be (x+1)^2, you times 7 by (x+1) not (x+1)^2, I don't understand why.

Comment: Because we only needed an extra factor of $(x+1)$ in the denominator of $\dfrac{7}{(x+1)}$ to get $(x+1)(x+1) = (x+1)^2$ in the denominator. So we multiplied both numerator and denominator of $\dfrac{7}{(x+1)}$ by $\dfrac{(x+1)}{(x+1)}$ giving us $\dfrac{7(x+1)}{(x+1)(x+1)} = \dfrac{(7(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$. Then we can simply add the numerators to get the result, since now the denominators of the fractions are equal.

Comment: So you can just take what you need and ignore the rest? Hmm..I thought you had to times the right hand fraction by the left denominator and the left hand fraction by the right denominator.

Comment: If we multiplied numerator and denominator by $(x+1)^2$, we'd end up with $\dfrac{7}{(x+1)} \cdot \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{(x+1)^2} = \dfrac{7(x+1)^2}{(x+1)^3}$, and we still wouldn't be able to subtract it from the other fraction!

Answer (score 1):

If x$\neq$1, you can cancel $(x-1)$ in the numerator and denominator of $\frac{(x - 1)(7x + 6)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)^2  }$ so, 
$$\frac{(x - 1)(7x + 6)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)^2  }-\frac{ 7}{  (x + 1)}=\frac{7x + 6}{(x + 1)^2  }-\frac{ 7}{  (x + 1)}$$

Now, if x$\neq$-1 you can multiply and divide $\frac{7}{x + 1}$ by $(x+1)$ and add the fractions:

$$\frac{7x + 6}{(x + 1)^2  }-\frac{ 7}{  (x + 1)}=\frac{7x + 6}{(x + 1)^2  }-\frac{7(x+1)}{  (x + 1)^2}=\frac{7x + 6-7(x+1)}{(x + 1)^2}=\frac{-1}{(x + 1)^2}$$

Comment: Why do you not times the right fraction by (x+1)^2?

Comment: @Cypras, because i need have a denominator in the two fractions such that both are equal, this, because you know that if i have two fractions $\frac{A}{B}$ and $\frac{C}{B}$ then, the sum of the 2 fractions is $\frac{A+C}{B}$ and so it is easier to add, (it is equivalent to searching the common denominator, which is the same thing amWhy said)

Comment: @amWhy, sorry, I started writing before, but when I published the answer I had not yet seen another answer.